# Get a HashSet out of the keys of a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have a pretty big (100'000s of entries) `HashMap`. Now, I need a `HashSet` containing all the keys from this `HashMap`. Unfortunately, `HashMap` only has a `keySet()` method which returns a `Set` but not a `HashSet`.

What would be an efficient way to generate such a `HashSet` using Java?

Comment: Why do you need a HashSet and not just a Set?

Comment: A method I have to call needs a HashSet and the corresponding code is wasn't written by me.

Comment: eww. whoever wrote that method needs a good talking-to. :)

Comment: +1 Your comment explains it all. Glad you found a solution. :-)

Comment: @Haes: You should know that there is a performance hit. When you construct the HashSet from keySet(), it will basically have to duplicate the entire set. I'm not sure how long it takes to do this on 100,000s of elements, but it's definitely going to eat up a lot of memory. I know you don't have another option, but this might give you more ammo to request whoever wrote the method to change it so it takes a Set rather than a HashSet. (And unless they are doing something really weird, they should be able to just change the parameter and the rest will work with no modification).

Comment: Unless this is a very bureaucratic project that method should be rewritten (HashSet should be replaced with set). If the method is too long and convoluted for refactoring - well this is a major problem. A method should do one thing and shouldn't exceed 10 lines (20 lines are justified only if a switch statement is used).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Why do you specifically need a HashSet?**

Any Set have the same interface, so typically can be used interchangeably, as good-practices requires that you use the Set interface for all of them.

---

If you really need so, you could create one from the other. For generic code, it could be:

```
    Map<B, V> map = ...;
    HashSet<B> set = new HashSet<B>(map.keySet());
```

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, why not just use `Set<B> set = map.keySet();` ?  If an actual HashSet is needed, `set` should be a HashSet, not a Set.  If `set` can be a `Set`, then there's no need to call the HashSet constructor

Comment: Kip: you're right. Actually, I used the following code: 
HashSet<B> set = new HashSet<B>(map.keySet());

Comment: _Why do you specifically need a HashSet?_ Because HashSet is serializable while LinkedKeySet is not :)

Comment: One reason why this would be needed is when "null" is used in the HashMap as a key.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the word 'efficient' is the key part of your question, and depending what you want to do with the set, it might be an idea to create your own subclass of HashSet which ignores the HashSet implementation and presents a view onto the existing map, instead.

As a partially implemented example, it might look something like:

```
public class MapBackedHashSet extends HashSet
{
    private HashMap theMap;

    public MapBackedHashSet(HashMap theMap)
    {
        this.theMap = theMap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) 
    {
        return theMap.containsKey(o);
    }

    /* etc... */
}
```

If you don't know how the class will be used, you'll need to take care to override all the relevant methods.

Comment: It should be a SetBackedHashSet to work for him, using a Set as the backing data.  The original object he's getting from `keySet()` is a Set, not a HashMap.

Comment: The point is that you don't need to extract the set in this way. This is to avoid creating a new hash from a potentially large number of objects.

Answer (score 4):

```
HashSet myHashSet = new HashSet(myHashMap.keySet());
```

Haven't tried it.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not create the `HashSet` from an existing `Set` ? But (more importantly) why are you worried about the implementation returned to you from the `keySet()` method ?

Answer (score 2):

Set set=new HashSet(map.keySet());